# Return ALL indices containing maximum element in a table R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a table such as this (first row are factors, second are frequencies):

```
    A  B  C
    5  9  9
```

I know I can return the *first* occurrence (B) easily. I am looking for a way to return ALL indices that tie for the max (obviously, B and C in this example).

I can (and have) done this with a script in more or less of a "standard" programming sort of way, but I was wondering if there's a short R method that does this in one pre-existing command/function.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `names(x)[x==max(x)]` where `x <- as.table(c(A=5,B=9,C=9))` - I suspect this is a duplicate, hence not putting this in the answer box.

Comment: It is most definitely a duplicate. I answered it last week with an answer I got 2 years earlier.

Comment: I suspected it was, but didn't find it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(x)[N == max(N)]$V1
#[1] "B" "C"
```